# Python: specify regex pattern that divides the string roughly into half and make a tuple

Tags: python

I have a string:

```
S = 'ABCKFDJRFMDLERKDFLKERWERJF'
```

I am trying to make a regex pattern that divides the string into half. I believe it's similar to:

```
word_1 = 'jupiter'
pattern_1 = re.compile('(\w+\s)'+word_1+'(\s\w+)')
```

But this is much more complicated because I need to first find the place that divides the string into half. What I want to do is:

For a function called divider,

```
split_S = divider('ABCKFNDNVMCNDSKDE' , 'NVM')
print(split_S) 
('ABCKFND','CNDSKDE)
```

I really don't understand what to start first in this situation. If it's difficult to understand my question, please do tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you don't even need a regex, just use `string.find()`:

```
def divider(s, splitter):
    idx = s.find(splitter)
    returrn s[:idx], s[idx+len(splitter):]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import re
S = 'ABCKFDJRFMDLERKDFLKERWERJF'
final_string = tuple(re.findall(".{"+str(len(S)//2)+"}", S))
```

Output:

```
('ABCKFDJRFMDLE', 'RKDFLKERWERJF')
```